# Tracking Incoming Redirects To Your Site

Tags: javascript, http

Is there a way in which I can find out if a user arrived at my site via a redirect?

Here's an example: There are two sites, first.com & second.com. Any request to first.com will do a 302 redirect to second.com. When the request at second.com arrives, is there anyway to know it was redirected from first.com?

Note that in this example you have no control over first.com. (In fact, it could be something bad, like kiddieporn.com.)

Also note, because it is a redirect, it will not be in the HTTP referrer header.

Comment: +1 might come really handy when writing an analytics script!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.referrer!='')
  alert('Welcome visitor, from: '+document.referrer);
```

Is that what you mean? (Perform your own checks for if "first.com" is within the referrer)

**EDIT**

However, you're right, most browsers do not send a referrer header with a 302. With that being said, I don't see a way of knowing where they came from. And without control of the redirecting site, it's up to the user to tell you they came from the original source.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: Somehow I pre-submitted the form, my apologies & update posted.